# Dynamically inflating the RecyclerView listItem with EditText string

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to learn how to use RecyclerViews and the best way to learn is by doing :) so I'm trying to transition from using a ListView in a simple to do list to a Recyclerview.  I'm trying to get the String value from the EditText and add that value to my RecyclerView list when the button is clicked.  The following are my implementations.

This is my custom adapter.  I'm using a ViewHolder to use a basic, single TextView custom list-item.

```
public class ItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemAdapter.ViewHolder>{

    private List<todo> todoList;

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        public TextView toDoTextView;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            toDoTextView = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.to_do);
        }
    }

    public ItemAdapter(List<todo> todoList){
        this.todoList = todoList;
    }

    @Override
    public ItemAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ItemAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        todo toDo = todoList.get(position);
        holder.toDoTextView.setText(toDo.getToDo());
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return todoList.size();
    }
}
```

And this is my MainActivity.  This is where I'm going to be adding my EditText values to my RecyclerView List.  The implementation is done in the `setOnClickListener` but it gives me an error.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {                                                                   

    private List<todo> items = new ArrayList<>();                                                                       
    private ItemAdapter itemAdapter;                                                                                    
    private RecyclerView listItemsRecyclerView;                                                                         
    EditText itemsInput;                                                                                                
    Button addingItems;                                                                                                 

    @Override                                                                                                           
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {                                                                
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);                                                                             
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);                                                                         

        itemsInput = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.to_do_editText);                                                       
        addingItems = (Button)findViewById(R.id.to_do_btn);                                                             
        listItemsRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.to_do_list);                                           

        final String todoItem = String.valueOf(itemsInput.getText());                                                   

        itemAdapter = new ItemAdapter(items);                                                                           

        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());                    
        listItemsRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);                                                          
        listItemsRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());                                               
        listItemsRecyclerView.setAdapter(itemAdapter);                                                                  

        addingItems.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {                                                     
            @Override                                                                                                   
            public void onClick(View view) {                                                                            
                if(todoItem != null){                                                                                   
                    items.add(todoItem);                                                                                
                    itemsInput.setText("");                                                                             
                }else {                                                                                                 
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please enter something to do", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();       
                }                                                                                                       
                itemAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();                                                                     
            }                                                                                                           
        });
```

This is my todo class:

```
public class todo {
    private String toDo;

    public todo(){}

    public todo(String somethingToDo){
        somethingToDo = toDo;
    }

    public String getToDo() {
        return toDo;
    }

    public void setToDo(String toDo) {
        this.toDo = toDo;
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: It just doesn't compile.  I want to know how to iterate a Recyclerview list through a button click.

Comment: `add(todo) in list cannot be applied to (String)`

Comment: In your `onClick` you're trying to add `todoItem` which is a String not a `todo`... it needs to be a `todo` object.

Comment: Okay so how can I add the user input into my listView?  Can you give me an example?

Comment: To get past that error you'd want to do something like `items.add(new todo().setText(itemsInput.getText()));`, depending on what your `todo` class looks like.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150237/discussion-between-onur-ozbek-and-digitalninja).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your code inside if condition inside button OnClickListener

```
if(todoItem != null){                      
    todo mTodo = new todo(todoItem); //Create object of todo using the input done by user.                                             
    items.add(mTodo);                                                                                
    itemsInput.setText("");                                                                             
}
```

Also your todo class constructor code is wrong

```
public todo(String somethingToDo){
        //somethingToDo = toDo;
       toDo = somethingToDo; //need to assign the value received as signature to the class variable.
}
```